# How to remove items from the touch bar?

Tags: catalina, touch-bar

I want to remove the man page button from the Terminal's touch bar on macOS Catalina. When I go to View > Customize Touch Bar… I am instructed to "drag items up from the touch bar to remove them." However, if I:

1. Try to drag the *representation of the man page button **on the screen** up* using the pointer, nothing happens.
2. If I try to drag the *representation of a space **on the screen** up* using the pointer, nothing happens.
3. If I try to drag the *man page button **on the touch bar** up* using my finger, there is not room for "up" and nothing happens. (I.e. I can shift the button left or right, but not get rid of it).

Here is what I mean by "on the screen":

[image: Toolbar editing overlay]

**How do I remove the man page button from the Terminal touch bar?**

The answer I am looking for will be highly detailed, as in, "Put your finger here, and move it like so," or "Click this widget, hold this key, and then…".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use the mouse and get the pointer in that popup window in your screen shot - then you move the mouse pointer down. Imagine moving the mouse pointer from the screen and down into the Touch Bar itself.

You'll now see an icon in the Touch Bar lights up - you can move the mouse left/right to get the "man page" icon selected. Then click and hold the mouse button and move the mouse up to remove it from the Touch Bar.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. :D I **might** have pulled my hair out trying to figure this out.